# Скрытие View при скролле RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, прокрутка

Есть несколько вьюх, которые прикреплены к родительскому элементу. Под ними находится нижний RecyclerView, прикрепленный к ним и к низу родитеского элемента.

[image: Макет формы]

Необходимо плавно свернуть эти вьюхи и увеличить высоту RecyclerView.

Comment: Называется collapsing toolbar. Вот пример статьи, где описывается, как это сделать https://medium.com/martinomburajr/android-design-collapsing-toolbar-scrollflags-e1d8a05dcb02

Comment: А есть ли варианты сделать это без использования NestedScrollView?

Comment: По идее любой скроллинг можно использовать. С RecyclerView я точно это делал.